# Assignment problem using Hungarian method

Tags: linear-programming, assignment-problem

There are five jobs to be assigned to five machines and associated cost matrix is as follows 
$$
\begin{matrix}
\text{Machine} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\text{Job A} & [11, &17, &8, &16, &20] \\
\text{Job B} & [9, &7, &12, &6, &15] \\
\text{Job C} & [13, &16, &15, &12, &16] \\
\text{Job D} & [21, &24, &16, &28, &26] \\
\text{Job E} & [14, &10, &12, &11, &15] 
\end{matrix}
$$
The question is now: Find the assignment of machines to jobs that will minimize the total cost?

I solved it using the Hungarian method but for job A and D I had only one zero that too in the same column. I don't know how to solve further if this happens.

Comment: Since this looks a lot like a homework question, it would be best to show you intermediate steps of your attempt to solve it

Comment: As a note, I voted to reject a tag edit of "self-study" because I think that would be a meta-tag. Not sure that we fully settled on that as a policy, but I think we were leaning that direction. (https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163/what-is-the-soft-question-tag) Also, welcome to OR.SE, @Tango!

Comment: @E. Tucke At Cross Validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/ , self-study tag is applied to all homework problems, and even for questions requesting help understanding passages in textbooks, even f being used in self-study outside any courses.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Sounds good! The tag seems accurate; it's more that it's a meta-tag. If the community wants to go that direction, that's fine by me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're applying the [matrix version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm#Matrix_interpretation) of the algorithm. 
When you happen to have only one $0$ for A and D the matrix is
\begin{align*}
\pmatrix{2&9&0&8&8\\2&1&6&0&5\\0&4&3&0&0\\4&8&0&12&6\\3&0&2&1&1}
\end{align*}
Now continue with [Step 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm#Matrix_interpretation): cover all zeros minimally, and adjust the weights. After that step you will find a solution.

Comment: That is exact matrix I got now when covering all zeros I have r=4 covering lines and since problem has n=5 since r<n.   STEP3:  now 1 is least uncovered element subtracting 1 from all uncover element and adding 1 to element at intersection of covering line I am left with matrix that has same problem only one zero in A and D but now r=n . Can i use same step again when I have r=n

Comment: The least uncovered element will be $2$. Note that line $5$ will be unmarked after step 3.